# How to make a UNIQUE constraint on a Date type column without taking year in regard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, unique-constraint

I have a "trips" table with date column (date of trip),but I need not to repeat the day of trip, so I want to know if I could do a unique constraint on a part of the date using sql server 2014.
 I create this table

```
    CREATE TABLE trips
     (
      ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null  ,
      day_of_trip date not null,
      time_of_trip time not null,
      cost money not null,
      passengers int not null,
      bus_id int not null,
      trans_comp_id int not null,
      route_id int not null,
      CONSTRAINT UK_time UNIQUE (day_of_trip,time_of_trip,bus_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (bus_id) REFERENCES bus(id),
      FOREIGN KEY (trans_comp_id) REFERENCES trans_comp(id),
      FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes_(id) 
       )
```

but when inserting data in day_of_trip just like 
first trip: 1/2/2015
second trip: 5/8/2015

it gives an error because of

```
 Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 7
 Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_time'. Cannot insert duplicate key  in object 'dbo.trips'. The duplicate key value is (2015-01-02, 06:20:00.0000000, 2).
```

I want to have more than one trip in 2015 but not on 1/2/2015.

Comment: Please edit your question with examples of valid and invalid dates.

Comment: is that editing useful? @GordonLinoff

Comment: Your constraint should be doing what you want.  It looks like your second insert is for `2015-01-02`, not `2015-05-08`.

Comment: If use `CONSTRAINT UK_day UNIQUE (day_of_trip)` you will have a constraint for each day so no more trip will allowed in that day ;).

Answer (score 1):

"I want to know if I could do a constraint on a part of the date using sql server 2014."

I assume you mean "unique constraint" given the title.  If this is your question, then the answer is "yes".  You do so by created computed columns and then building a unique index on those.

Here is one way:

```
alter table <table> add mmdd as (month(date)*100 + day(date) );
create unique index idx_table_mmdd on <table>(mmdd);
```

Comment: oh yes i mean unique, I edited the question. can you please tell me what is *100 using for ?

Comment: @user3159060 . . . That just produces a column in the form of mmdd as a number.  Seems convenient for demonstrating a unique constraint on month and day.